# Knapsack beginner python

Tags: python, recursion, knapsack-problem

I have trouble finding a solution to the knapsack problem that that is suitable for beginners.

```
def fill_bag(max_weight, value, weight):
    # Zero Weight
    if max_weight <= 0:
        return 0
    # Invalid parameters
    if len(value) != len(weight):
        raise ValueError
    # Empty values
    elif value == [] or weight == []:
        return 0

    # Include current item in bag and recur for remaining items with decreased capacity
    include = value[-1] + fill_bag(max_weight - weight[-1], value[:-1], weight[:-1])

    # Exclude current item from bag and recur for remaining items
    exclude = fill_bag(max_weight, value[:-1], weight[:-1])

    return max(include, exclude)

print(fill_bag(10, [20, 5, 10, 40, 15, 25], [1, 2, 3, 8, 7, 4]))
```

Should return 60, but in my case it returns 65.
While debugging i noticed that the max_weight of exclude is carried on from the include from before. Is the problem that I somehow don't reset the max_weight/capacity?

Comment: can you fix indentation please.

Comment: you include an element without testing if there is actual room for it

Comment: test on this bag: print(fill_bag(10, [1000, 5, 10, 40, 15, 25], [1000, 2, 3, 8, 7,4]))

Comment: Ahhhh. I see. Thank you Christian.